# Can someone help explain this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#AddMoreErrors,#AddMoreMime,#AddMoreRemote').live('click',function(){
    var newRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr class="'+newRow.attr('class')+'">'+newRow.html()+'</tr>').find('span').removeAttr('id').addClass('removetr').html('Del');                  
});
```

I wrote the above jquery code and this is what it does: When someone clicks on "add more" it finds the nearest `tr`, replicates it into another `tr` and appends it to the first one. Then it finds all the `span`s, removes its `id` and adds a new `class` and changes the text.

Now what surprised me was `find('span').removeAttr('id').addClass('removetr').html('Del');`

I know I could do `removeAttr` on `span` but how did `addClass` and `html` also get applied on `span`?

Comment: Wait... so you have no idea at all what **you were writing**?

Comment: i had other ideas and thought this may work but when it worked on first shot i was surprised

Comment: Oh alright, that's fine.

Comment: It is popularly called *method chaining*. Crockford calls it the *cascade*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery returns object of element after each operation on which it is performed, and execution order are from left to right. So its `.removeAttr('id')` will be on span and that span object will be returned. Similarly `.addClass('removetr')` and `.html('Del');` are performed.

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery methods return `this`, so:

```
find('span').removeAttr('id').addClass('removetr').html('Del');
```

Means the same as:

```
var foo = find('span');
foo.removeAttr('id');
foo.addClass('removetr')
foo.html('Del');
```

Comment: what do u mean . I have understood they both do they same(urs & mine). But can u give me some ore details

Comment: The return value of `foo.removeAttr('id')` is `foo`

Comment: oh okay so what all method return foo

Comment: Most do. Sometimes it depends on context.

Comment: can u give me some more info on it as "depends on context". Thanks

Comment: Some methods do. Some do not. Some methods may or may not depending on if you give them arguments or not. Check the API reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to know why you can chain jQuery commands one after another, that's because every jQuery function return "this". You can easily do the same when working with [IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
function doSth() {
   // Some logic
   return this;
}
```

What actually happens the is, that you return the object after each method call and continue working on the same object you called the method from before.

That means that

```
$("#sel").method().method2().method3();
```

is exactly the same as writing

```
var sel = $("sel");
sel.method();
sel.method2();
sel.method3();
```

Only that it's shorter, looks nicer and you don't need to save the variable in case you don't need it again afterwards.

That way, you can write one function after another and you'll always have the complete jQuery function after the function is executed.

So you also see, why all three methods are executed on the same object: It's the way chaining works. By calling "$" you create a new object. And all methods are then executed on that object.

Unless of course, the function actually returns a value. Then, this won't work.

```
function getSth() {
    return "value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called method chaining. Each of those jQuery methods (`removeAttr()`, `addClass()`, `html(val)`) returns the jQuery object to which it belongs. This means you can call further methods using the dot notation.

Comment: i know chain that why i used it but how did all 3 get applied on span

Comment: @WebDeveloper Quentin has explained it better than I did in [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239190/can-some-one-explain-the-below-jquery-code/7239221#7239221)